# How to use Selenium Locators in RIDE tool

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, robotframework

I am new to RIDE and Robot Framework , Please suggest me the best solution for Identifying the Elements/Objects. I tried using Selenium IDE, Firebug and Fire Robot. But after taking the XPath and ID's from Selenium IDE and Firebug it is not recognizing with RIDE.My application consists of Frames.

Comment: how can we possibly answer this without seeing even a single line of code?

Comment: Hi, I am using ID  as -id=C41_W177_V178_V180_V181_ztcnsearchmsisdn_ngp, it is working fine. When I use XPATH as xpath=.//input[contains(@id,'ztcnsearchmsisdn_ngp')] , it is not working.But I checked it with Selenium IDE , the above XPATH is highlighting in Selenium IDE. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If RIDE is not recognizing the Xpath, then use the ID.   I've found with using RIDE that it's better to use the ID or div, rather than Xpath anyway,  even if it works fine in IDE.  I found that Firepath is a great tool for finding locators for use in RIDE.